# Ошибка при проверки оплаты Qiwi Api

Tags: python, qiwi

После того, как вызываю функция проверки оплаты, оно возвращает мне пустой JSON.
Ошибка, которую выдает: `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Код:

```
def check_payment(user_id):
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    s = requests.Session()
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token_qiwi
    parameters = {'rows': '5'}
    h = session.get('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v1/persons/{}/payments'.format(number_qiwi),params=parameters)
    req = json.loads(h.text)
    result = cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM check_payment WHERE user_id = {user_id}').fetchone()
    comment = result[1]
    for i in range(len(req['data'])):
        if str(comment) in str(req['data'][i]['comment']) and str('643') in str(req['data'][i]["sum"]["currency"]):
            info = profile(user_id)
            balance = float(info[2]) + float(req["data"][i]["sum"]["amount"])
            cursor.execute(f'UPDATE users SET balance = {balance} WHERE user_id = "{user_id}"')
            conn.commit()
            cursor.execute(f'DELETE FROM check_payment WHERE user_id = "{user_id}"')
            conn.commit()
            return req["data"][i]["sum"]["amount"]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
conn.close()
```

Comment: с таким кодом помимо python и само киви должно бросать ошибку 

Comment: @MaximChyorny, а в чем проблема, если не секрет? Больше, чем половина кода взята из документации киви. Тем не менее, это раньше работало, а сейчас перестало, хотя я ничего и не менял.